# Mediawiki - Method for $wgActionPaths on nginx

Tags: mediawiki, nginx

I'm trying to set up action path rewriting on my mediawiki 1.33 install with nginx 1.14.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.2fpm.

All the documentation I've been able to find on mediawiki.org and via internet searching explain how to set this up for Apache. Has anyone set this feature up on nginx?

Answer (score -2):

I think, this documentation hits the nail: http://wiki.seb35.fr/Tutorial:Beautiful_MediaWiki_URLs

Comment: A link only answer is not high quality.  Please answer the question here as we are trying to build a repository of knowledge on this site.  Links often go bad, so a link only answer becomes useless.   It is also not good user experience to force somebody to click off the site to read the answer.

Comment: I don't think so. Its not a good manner for the web health to create redundant sources. One should care about sites too, which deliver self-sufficient answers to questions asked at SO. Rewriting without cross site canonical, which isn't used by SO, is just like... profiting at costs of other?

Comment: To be clear, answers cannot be copied here verbatim from another source without permission. That would be plagiarism. Canonical tags are used when there is duplicate content from verbatim copying. It is best to write your own full answer here with links to your sources.

Comment: I differentiate my answers: sometimes, where i can help with my knowledge, i give answers based on it. But sometimes, i know pretty nothing about the topic of the question - but, neverthenless, i can give help, because the topic starter isn't able to _find_ the answer by itself. It would be a nonsense, if i would try to explain something, what i don't understand by myself - but the topis starter, he understands the answer at the cited link much better, if he reads it NOT in my non understanding summary:)

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to point users in the right direction.  I'd suggest using comments rather than answers for helpful links.   Stack Exchange considers link only answers not even to be answers.   See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)